# Does adding <uses-permission> tag in AndroidManifest.xml require for application targeted Android 6.0 and above

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am aware about the changes introduced in Android 6.0/SDKVersion 23 regarding the app permission. There is excellent discussion on this topic in the below post.

["Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

Now post Android 6.0, we require to verify and seek various permission during run-time as discussed [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

With this, Does adding  tag in **AndroidManifest.xml** will have any meaning/use case post Android 6.0 targeted devices only?. Or we can remove these entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to list your permissions in the manifest. Quoting the developer page covering [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest, as described in [Declaring Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html).

If you don't, you'll probably end up with an `Exception` at runtime when trying to check or request them.